# When to use absolute imports

Tags: python, import

I'm changing a bunch of old python code that is occasionally running into name collisions between packages.  I have a question about when absolute imports should be used and whether it would be proper to import same-level modules by name only.

```
/package/
/package/__init__.py
/package/subA
/package/subA/__init__.py
/package/subA/moduleA.py
/package/subA/moduleB.py
/package/subB
/package/subB/__init__.py
/package/subB/moduleA.py
/package/subB/moduleB.py
```

Should every import statement within the package look like:

```
import package.subX.moduleX
```

or

```
from package.subX import moduleX
```

What about in the subpackage `__init__.py` files.  Would it be wrong to simply put

```
import moduleA
import moduleB
```

Or, in /package/subA/moduleA.py, would it be wrong to simply put:

```
import moduleB
```

Comment: you could always alias as well if you want to save some characters throughout your code, as in `from package.subA import moduleA as a_moduleA` and `from package.subB import moduleA as b_moduleA`, seems kind of messy to me, but it's another option...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Relative imports turned out to be a very bad idea, even though they were the default behavior for long. You can find quite a few questions on this site where someone simply named their file after a builtin module and broke their application with weird error messages.

That's why it's always a good to do absolute imports by referencing your project *everywhere*, including packages.

In short, use this style:

```
import myproject.mypackage
from myproject.mypackage.myfile import MyClass
```

Quote from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly
>   discouraged.
>   Always use the absolute package path for all imports.
>   Even now that [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) is fully implemented in Python 2.5,
>   its style of explicit relative imports is actively discouraged;
>   absolute imports are more portable and usually more readable.

Comment: +1 with absolute imports it's easy to see what you're going to get.

Comment: As of September 213, this answer is wrong because PEP8 has changed. For example: "However, explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports, especially when dealing with complex package layouts where using absolute imports would be unnecessarily verbose"

Comment: @glarrain But absolute imports are still recommended over relative

Comment: @endolith recommended by whom? You mean as popular convention, a PEP or what?

Comment: @glarrain Yes: "Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved … explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports" https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports "Absolute imports are preferred because they are quite clear and straightforward" https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/