# When or why to use relative imports in Python

Tags: python, import, module, package

Are there any rules or guidelines concerning when to use relative imports in Python? I see them in use all the time, such as in the Flask web framework. When searching for this topic, I only see articles on how to use relative imports, but not *why*.

So is there some special benefit to using:

```
from . import x
```

rather than:

```
from package import x
```

Moreover, I noticed that [a related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811548/1918127) mentions that relative imports are discouraged. Yet people still continue to use them.

Comment: Regarding the [referenced SO answer discouraging relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811548/1918127), there's also a highly upvoted counterargument, "As of September 213 [sic], this answer is wrong because PEP8 has changed...".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check out [PEP 328's section on relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports)

The rationale seems to be as written:

> Several use cases were presented, the most important of which is being able to rearrange the structure of large packages without having to edit sub-packages. In addition, a module inside a package can't easily import itself without relative imports.

Comment: "a module inside a package can't easily import itself" What even does that mean?

Comment: @endolith Imagine having a package `a`, with a subpackage `b`. Without relative imports, module `a.b.m` can't import itself without knowing not only that it's part of package `b`, but also of package `a`.

Comment: Why a module inside a package will need to import itself?